# Is it possible to create the variable with random and static values? R

Tags: r

Is it possible to create the variable with first 40 elements with 0, from 60 to 100 1 and from 41 to 59 random 1 or 0. R

Comment: akrun's answer is legit. If you want to control the probability of being a 1 (or not being a 0) you can use `rbinom` instead of `sample`. `rbinom(19,1,.5)` if you want a 50% chance of being a 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use `rep` with `sample`

```
c(rep(0, 40), sample(0:1, 19, replace = TRUE), rep(1, 41))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option

```
replace(
  sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE),
  c(1:40, 60:100),
  rep(c(0, 1), c(40, 41))
)
```